# How to make a HTML Form interactive?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a site with an interactive HTML Form.
But I can't seem to make it work. What I mean by interactive is that for example: If I have a drink choice between:
Cola
Fanta
Sprite
Pepsi

When I select Pepsi I want it to show another HTML form which let's me select something related to the first thing I chose. For example if I chose Pepsi it would show me this:

Pepsi Cola
Pepsi Orange
Pepsi Banana

and then when I choose one of Those it shows me another HTML form which let's me choose another thing Related to my first and second choices. For example: If I chose Pepsi then Pepsi Orange it would let me choose between:

2000
2013
2020

So far I've tried if Scripts (with Javascript)

Here's What I tried:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select name="drink">
    <option value="cola">Cola</option>
    <option value="fanta">Fanta</option>
    <option value="sprite">Sprite</option>
    <option value="pepsi">Pepsi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    if (drink=pepsi) {

        <html>
        <form>
      <select name="variant">
     <option value="pcola">Pepsi Cola</option>
     <option value="orange">Pepsi Orange</option>
     <option value="banana">Pepsi Banana</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
 </html>
}
</script>


    <script>
    if (variant=orange) {

        <html>
        <form>
      <select name="year">
     <option value="2000">2000</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
 </html>
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing basic coding structures and syntax

Comment: Think of the approach of one form with multiple selects. Then based on the styles, show or hide (using style.display and style.visibility) based on the javascript onchange event of a select statement. Research those terms and you will see what I am saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the level of interactivity you have described, you won't need `javascript`.

You can achieve what you are describing using just 2 lines of `css`:

```
li ul {display:none;}
li input:checked + ul {display:block;}
```

**Example:**

```css
li ul {display:none;}
li input:checked + ul {display:block;}
```

```html
<form>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="drink" value="Cola" />Cola</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="drink" value="Fanta" />Fanta</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="drink" value="Sprite" />Sprite</li>

<li><input type="radio" name="drink" value="Pepsi" />Pepsi
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="flavour" value="pepsiCola" />Pepsi Cola</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="flavour" value="pepsiOrange" />Pepsi Orange
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="date" value="2000" />2000</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="date" value="2013" />2013</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="date" value="2020" />2020</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="flavour" value="pepsiBanana" />Pepsi Banana</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: This is pretty much the only one I can understand out of the all the answers and I have one more question, How would I make it so after I choose something it would display a few pictures/text?

Comment: The example I've posted above is a sort of "bare bones" example. You can use the nested list structure above and fill the list items with pictures, text, animations etc. And you can style the list items to appear anywhere on the page etc.

Answer (score 1):

Learn something about JS method: `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, ...

For eg.:

```
if (document.getElementById('value') == 'cola')
```

...return value of your choice, next use it to change content of your form....

Use '=' to assign, but '==' in if constructions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `script` elements with `type` set to `text/html` to store `form` `html` strings , attaching `.onchange` and `.onsubmit` events to `document` to handle dynamic content; using `.innerHTML` to append `script` element content to `document.body`; adjusting condition at `if` to use strict equality `===` operator; set previous `form` `select` and `input type="submit"` elements `disabled` attribute to `true`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/html" id="pepsi">
    <form name="variant">
      <select name="variant">
        <option value="pcola">Pepsi Cola</option>
        <option value="orange">Pepsi Orange</option>
        <option value="banana">Pepsi Banana</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" disabled>
    </form>
  </script>
  <script type="text/html" id="orange">
    <form name="year">
      <select name="year">
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" disabled>
    </form>
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="initial">
    <select name="drink">
      <option value="cola">Cola</option>
      <option value="fanta">Fanta</option>
      <option value="sprite">Sprite</option>
      <option value="pepsi">Pepsi</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" disabled>
  </form>
  <script>
    document.onchange = function(event) {
      event.target.parentElement
        .querySelector("input")
        .removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
    document.onsubmit = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      var drink = event.target.querySelector("select").value;
      if (drink === "pepsi" || drink === "orange") {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" 
        + document.getElementById(drink).innerHTML;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length -1; i++) {
        var form = document.forms[i];
        form.querySelector("select").setAttribute("disabled", true)
        form.querySelector("input").setAttribute("disabled", true)
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```