# Unable to load a JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("./data/test.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
      });
    });
```

How can I load a local file that is not being hosted on a webserver?

---

I get an error in the console

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

The file is being hosted on my C drive

Comment: check the browser console, ctrl+shift+j

Comment: Maybe if you use `../data/test.json` instead

Comment: Which browser was used to request data ?

Comment: Testing and Developing on Chrome. Deployed with IE11

Comment: @softwareisfun See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/32996188#32996188

Comment: yea but that wont help me when im launching in IE 11

Comment: _"yea but that wont help me when im launching in IE 11"_  Does ie11 log same error at `console` ?

Comment: even after launching chrome --allow-file-access-from-files, same issue

Comment: Oddly it doesnt log any error but the contents of my JSON file do not display in the console

Comment: _"even after launching chrome --allow-file-access-from-files, same issue"_ Not viewed this occurring previously at chromium or chrome. Can include launcher lines at Question ?

Comment: _"Oddly it doesnt log any error but the contents of my JSON file do not display in the console"_ Try chaining `.fail()` to `$.getJSON()` call to log errors; also try using full path to json file

Comment: I changed the Browser emulation in IE11 to IE10 and my contents from my JSON file appeared. When it's Edge (default), nothing appears.

Comment: _"I changed the Browser emulation in IE11 to IE10"_ Is Question concerning chrome or ie browser ?

Comment: Using IE11, I pressed F12 then changed the browser to 10. My JSON spit out the contents as I had expected. However the issues are that it's not doing the same in Chrome or IE11. This HTML file will be deployed on 800 PC's and we can't manually change each browser emulation to 10 or install Chrome

Comment: _"This HTML file will be deployed on 800 PC's and we can't manually change each browser emulation to 10 or install Chrome"_ Is browser being run in a `vm` ? Not certain interpret Question correctly ? Are there both chrome and ie browsers used at the n-PC's ?

Comment: The PC's are not running in a VM. Only on my development machine, I have both browsers. I prefer Chrome's debugging tools over IE. However when the product is ready, it will need to launch in IE11 for Windows 7

Comment: _"However when the product is ready, it will need to launch in IE11 for Windows 7"_ Why test on chrome if application requires *indows , ie 11 environment ? See also  https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Im developing in Chrome because I prefer the tools better. I am testing on both. Usually my apps work in both. But for some reason I can't load the JSON file locally

Comment: What is purpose of testing loading local file if application is for consumption over n PC's ? Will all n-PC's be loading file locally in same manner as test at chrome ? Or, will all n-PC's be loading same external json file ?

Comment: Yes, they will use a storage server. \\Server\Path\WebApp\data\test.json

Comment: _"Yes"_ file will be at each individual PC ?

Comment: the file will be accessible via shared file on a server. The actual html, css, js will not be on the local HD. In either case, there is no web server

Comment: Tried using a `Worker` to serve file ?

Comment: how would that help? Web Worker appears to be the same as threading

Comment: Could embed json file within `html` file, serve json file from same `html` document to itself. This could be done without web worker as well

Comment: I didn't think about that. Would it go in my script tag or somewhere else?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116459/how-to-make-a-html-form-interactive/ using `script` elements. Another option could be to embed json file within `data-*` attribute of `html` or other element. Alternatively, could use `shadowDOM` , `template` element